# Метод Горнера

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте, помогите мне разобраться с одной проблемой. Мне надо написать программу, которая находит целые корни многочлена по схеме Горнера, через делите свободного члена. Программа считает, но в ответе постоянно выдает ответ "нет".

Программа:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vcl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused
using namespace std;
char bufRus[256];

char *Rus(const char *text)
{
    CharToOem(text, bufRus);
    return bufRus;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    register unsigned int i;
    unsigned int n;

    cout << Rus("Введите количество элементов: ");
    cin >> n;                        //4

    if (n < 1) {
        cerr << Rus("Требуется хотя бы два элемента.") << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    double *a = new double[n];
    double *b = new double[n];

    cout << Rus("Введите делитель свободного члена: ");
    double c;
    cin >> c;                        // 2

    cout << Rus("Введите исходн. элем.:") << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    cout << endl;                // 1 -1 -8 12

    /* Рисуем верхнюю рамку */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "+-------";
    cout << "+" << endl;

    /* Выводим исходные элементы */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "| " << a[i] << "t";
    cout << "|" << endl;

    /* Снова рамка */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "+-------";
    cout << "+" << endl;

    /* По условию, первый элемент b равен первому элементу a */
    b[0] = a[0];
    cout << "| " << *b << "t";
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = b[i - 1] * c;
        /* В этом месте b[i] будет равно значению, записываемому во вторую строчку */
        b[i] += a[i];
        cout << "| " << b[i] << "t";
    }
    cout << "+" << endl;

    /* И ещё одна завершающая рамка */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "+-------";
    cout << "+" << endl << endl;
    if (b[n - 1] == 0)
        cout << Rus("Ответ: ") << c << endl;
    else
        cout << Rus("Ответ: нет");
    delete[]b;
    delete[]a;
    getch();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала сократите код до осмысленного минимума. Потом, у меня вот так всё прекрасно считается и выводится "OK":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()  
{  
    int c = 2;
    int n = 4;
    double a[] = { 1, -1, -8, 12 };
    double b[4] = { 1 };

    for( int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        b[i] = b[i-1] * c;
        //printf( "a[%d]=%f, b[%d]=%f\n", i, a[i], i, b[i] );
        b[i] += a[i];
        //printf( "b[%d]=%f\n", i, b[i] );
    }
    printf( "%s\n", b[n-1] == 0 ? "OK" : "Fail" );
    return 0;
}
```

Посему есть подозрение, что дело в использовании double, или [не]использовании math.h (??? это может зависеть от компилятора), или в конструкции b[n-1]==0. Попробуйте обойтись вообще без double для пробы.

Comment: Все равно программа отвечает, что нет корней